# Spark: How to build semi-additive metrics or aggregate sum over a portion of a column?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to reproduce some of the analytics I do in traditional BI within spark.  The technical term used is how to build semi-additive metrics, but it might help if I explain what that means.

For example, say I have a list of stock holding amounts every day.  Yesterday I had 100, today I have 50.  This is a semi-additive metric because you don't have 150.  You have 50.  So you only want to sum things up for the most current day.  But, something like sales would be fully additive and you'd sum over all sales for the entire year, for example.

So the question is how do I build a semi-additive metric using agg and sum?  And how do I write the agg statement that showed both semi-additive and fully-additive metrics together?  For example:

```
val stocks = (Seq(
             ("2019-05-01", 1, "FB", 1058.45, 100000),
             ("2019-05-01", 1, "NVDA", 40058.45, 150000),
             ("2019-05-03", 1, "FB", 8058.45, 80000),
             ("2019-05-04", 1, "FB", 11058.45, 75000),  // Latest FB entry for account 1 
             ("2019-05-05", 1, "NVDA", 50058.45, 125000),  // Latest NVDA entry for account 1
             ("2019-05-01", 2, "FB", 1058.45, 200000),
             ("2019-05-02", 2, "NVDA", 5058.45, 125000),
             ("2019-05-03", 2, "NVDA", 5058.45, 115000),
             ("2019-05-05", 2, "FB", 1058.45, 65000),   // latest FB entry for account 2
             ("2019-05-06", 2, "NVDA", 5058.45, 105000)  // latest NVDA entry for account 2
          ).toDF("date", "symbol", "account", "sale", "current_holdings"))

 stocks
     .groupBy( stocks.col("symbol") )
     .add( sum("earnings"), sum("current_holdings") )
     .show()
```

What this would produce:

```
+------+---------+----------------+
|symbol|sale     |current_holdings|
+------+---------+----------------+
|    FB| 34291.80|        520000.0|
|  NDVA|105292.20|        525500.0|
+------+---------+----------------+
```

Should produce:

```
+------+---------+----------------+
|symbol|sale     |current_holdings|
+------+---------+----------------+
|    FB| 34291.80|          140000|
|  NDVA|105292.20|          230000|
+------+---------+----------------+
```

In the expected the difference is only in the current_holdings column which would be summing up all of the latest entries across all accounts.  So adding the latest entries for FB you get:

```
FB = 75000 + 65000
NVDA = 125000 + 105000
```

I've looked at WindowFunctions, but I can't see how to specify the conditions of the sum except for specific indexes within the partitions, and that would be difficult if say I need to sum everything from a specific month.  How is this done with Spark?

PS:
Please the excuse the strange example I had to adapt it for public viewing.

PSS:
I've also made this pretty hard because the latest date for each account / symbol doesn't line up with a predicable boundary.  In my specific situation I'm actually trying to sum things up that only belong to the last month of a given time period (year, quarter, etc).  I expect that to be a simpler situation, but I wanted to fully explore semi-additive use cases so I made the problem hard.

Comment: can you explain the logic in more detail?

Comment: Ok I think that should help make it clearer how you need to sum those values to match the expected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PySpark solution which can be modified to its equivalent `Scala` code.

Using `row_number` to number rows per account,symbol in the `desc` order of date and summing up the holding value of the `first` row per group.

```
w=Window.partitionBy(stocks.account,stocks.symbol).orderBy(stocks.date.desc())
stocks = stocks.withColumn('rnum',row_number().over(w))
w1 = Window.partitionBy(stocks.symbol)
stocks = stocks.withColumn('sales',sum(stocks.sale).over(w1)).withColumn('holdings',sum(when(stocks.rnum==1,stocks.current_holdings).otherwise(0)).over(w1))
#Final selection
stocks.select(stocks.symbol,stocks.sales,stocks.holdings).distinct().show()
```